# Mirror 4 HD Desktops on one 4K Screen

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, vnc, 4k-resolution

here's the scenario:
We want to be able to share our Screens on one 4k TV for meetings. So anyone (all windoes pcs) taking part can come up the screen using a network connection, up to 4 persons. HD is 1920x1080, our 4k TV (which is hooked up to a PC) has 3840x2160 - so it should fit in nicely.

Currently we use VNC and mRemoteNG (on the TV side) to achive this. But there are some flaws:

- VNC generates aftefacts
- VNC lags a lot
- The screens are still scaled, due to some elemets of mRemoteNG taking up space.

I'd love to use RDP for the task, because it is resource friendly on both, the client and the server and seems to work a lot better. I also experimented with screencast technology, but this was hard to configure and resource hungry.

So the question ist - can I use RDP to mirror a real screen (instead of remote controlling a virtual screen, what you normally do)? Does the protocoll allow this? If it's allowed by the protocoll, but there are no implementations we might want to dig into it a litte more.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please add the TV model?

Comment: We are using a Hisense LTDN58XT880. But I don't see how this could affect the setup, so I won't add it to the question.